# How to remove last 5 characters from a string in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to remove "time" from rows in column using pandas '06/07/2020 14:00'
How can I access last 6 characters of a string to replace it using str.replace("x", "")
Your advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: `.str[:-5]` to get string without 5 last chars.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? if you have a datetime object it might be easier to edit that so you don't get any weird behavior

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {'datetime': ['06/07/2020 14:00', '06/07/2020 16:00', '06/07/2020 18:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date'] = df['datetime'].str[:-6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.str[:-5]
```

is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
time_and_date = '06/07/2020 14:00'
only_time = time_and_date.split(' ')[1]
# or
only_time = time_and_date[-5:]
```

if you want to replace the time in the string, you can do it like this:

```
time_and_date = '06/07/2020 14:00'
new_value_to_be_placed = 'Some value'
new_time_and_date = time_and_date.split(' ')[0] + new_value_to_be_placed
```

Answer (score -1):

Use apply and lambda expressions. If your column is really a string:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
d1 = {'my_date_str': ['06/07/2020 14:00', '08/07/2020 14:00'], 'my_date': [datetime.now(), datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10)]}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d1['my_date_str_new'] = d1['my_date_str'].apply(lambda x: x[:10])
```

if your column is a datetime object:

```
d1['my_date_new'] = d1['my_date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

Comment: My column is a string and do not really want to convert it into the datetime object. Just remove the time characters from a string across all rows in the column.

Comment: The first solution is for strings of course and for the whole column.